# Que signifie la locution "et de" en debut de phrase ?

Tags: grammaire, infinitif, de

Je me suis mise à la lecture de journaux. Je rencontre beaucoup la locution "et de" en debut de certaines phrase. Que signifie-t-elle ?

Par exemple : "Et de rajouter le ministre de l'économie sur l'état du financement des partenaires sur le deuxième trimestre de l'année etc ......"

Answer (score 3):

Il faut remarquer que ce *et de* est toujours suivi de l'infinitif. Cette tourne s'appelle l'**infinitif de narration**.
Il faut noter que dans cette construction le *et* et le *de* ne sont pas forcément conjoint. Le sujet est souvent exprimé entre le *et* et le *de*. Dans l'exemple figurant dans la question on aurait pu avoir :

- Et le ministre de l'économie de rajouter ...

Si le sujet a été nommé auparavant il n'est pas repris :

- Et de conclure : "Quand on fait croire aux gens que la politique du gouvernement serait une politique ([Interview](https://www.europe1.fr/politique/dire-que-macron-et-le-pen-ca-se-vaut-cest-irresponsable-denonce-marlene-schiappa-4051619))<sup>1</sup>.

*Le bon usage*,Grevisse, 10<sup>e</sup> édition @750, 3° :

> Dans des propositions affirmatives se rapportant au passé et commençant généralement par *et*, pour exprimer une action se déclenchant vivement, et conséquence d’une autre action qui précède : c’est l’infinitif dit « historique » ou « de narration » ; il est toujours au présent, toujours introduit par *de* et presque toujours accompagné d’un sujet. *Et boquillons de perdre leur outil - Et de crier pour se le faire rendre.* (Jean de La Fontaine)<sup>2</sup>.
> [...]
> Dans l'ancienne langue, [...] précédé de *or* et de *de* avec l'article  défini, l’infinitif servait à exprimer une exhortation pressante : *Pincédé, or du bien pinchier* (Jean Bodel)! [Pincédé, veille à bien pincé] […]. — C’est peut-être ce tour qui est à l’origine de notre infinitif de narration (mais on admet plus généralement que l’infinitif de narration appartient à la catégorie des phrases nominales, sans verbe personnel. — L’infinitif de narration s’est développé au XV<sup>e</sup> siècle ; considéré comme familier au XVII<sup>e</sup> siècle, il passe aujourd’hui pour élégant et pour un peu recherché. — À noter qu’il a pu autrefois être introduit par *à* : *El bon prestre à soy retirer* (Saint-Simon).

La [BDL](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=4216) précise que « [La valeur temporelle de l'infinitif de narration ou infinitif historique] est celle du passé simple (ou du passé composé), temps de la narration par excellence. »

Cette construction est effectivement littéraire et peu employée à l'oral, mais on la rencontre souvent dans la presse. On pourra lire à ce sujet [l'article](https://journals.openedition.org/discours/4343) que Frédéric Torterat lui a consacrée dans le n° 3/2008 de la revue *discours*  « Citation et textologie du journal : ce que vient faire l’infinitif de narration dans les colonnes des quotidiens ».

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> Dans cet exemple, *et* fait le lien avec les paroles, directes et rapportées, de la ministre. *De* introduit la suite des propos de la ministre. Cela revient à dire : « Elle conclut ensuite que... ».
C'est un emploi identique à l'[exemple [1]](https://journals.openedition.org/discours/4343#tocto2n3) de l'article cité ci-dessous : « l’IN apparaît comme un élément de transition du discours narrativisé (DN) au discours direct (DD) ». C'est à dire qu'on a un discours rapporté (« narrativisé ») et *et de* nous fait passer au discours direct.</sup>

<sup><sup>2</sup> *[Le bûcheron et mercure](https://www.poesie-francaise.fr/jean-de-la-fontaine/fable-le-bucheron-et-mercure.php)*. *Et* sert à faire le lien avec l'histoire du bûcheron auquel Mercure a fait retrouver sa cognée. Ce *et* introduit aussi un changement de direction dans le récit ; si ensuite tous les bûcherons disent avoir perdu leur outil c'est parce que (**conséquence**) Mercure avait proposé une cognée en or au premier.

Ce changement dans le récit est « vif » car en peu de mots l'infinitif narratif permet de dire que « étant au courant de cette histoire les bûcherons se mirent tous à perdre leur outil... ».</sup>

Comment: Salut. Je sais ce que c'est maintenant. Mais toujours pas comment le compendre. " ... action qui se declenche vivement conséquence d'une autre action ..." donc la phrase avec le ministre signifie que le ministre à "rajouter" des commentaire sur "l'état du financement" à cause d'un autre fait décrit dans une phrase précédente ?

Comment: @tommy   Pour expliquer à partir de l'exemple de ta question il aurait fallu que je connaisse ce qui précède. Je me suis donc servi de mes exemples, j'espère que c'est plus clair. Dans le domaine journalistique les significations peuvent être multiples, l'article auquel je renvoie explique ça en (très grand) détail.

Comment: oh la la... Je peux pas lire tout cet article moi. Je suis pas tres assidue ni intelligente. Pour ça que j'ai poser directement la questio  ici. Juste un ptit exemple sera bon. En tout gros merci déjà.

Comment: @J'ai essayé de faire une réponse assez large car certains peuvent être intéressées. Si tu donnes ce qui précède la phrase que tu donnes on pourra certainement affiner sur ton exemple. Je soupçonne que c'est un cas de passage du discours direct au discours indirect (ou le contraire) mais pas obligé. En tous les cas question intéressante et jamais posée. Si les réponses ne sont pas claires il suffit de continuer à dialoguer... on peut toujours améliorer les réponses, la coopération marche en général assez bien ici.